# Non-linear scaling of data

Tags: python, feature-scaling

I have a set of numbers in a range between 1 to 5, heavily skewed towards 3. How can I (preferably in python) non-linearly scale the numbers so the difference between the numbers is more pronounced?

I need the resulting scaled numbers to be between -1 to 1.

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example of such data, and state the purpose of your intended analysis? By "skewed towards 3" do you mean predominantly 3s?